# convert txt file with mixed spaces/tabs to tabs only (where possible)

Tags: shell, tabs, whitespace

I have some source code file which has mixed tabs/spaces and I want to convert it to a file where it has automatically replaced all indentation spaces by tabs for a given tab space length (i.e. for example tab = 2 spaces).

Any easy solution (with common Unix tools, MacOSX, bash or zsh)? Some sed script or Python command or so?

Thanks,
Albert

Comment: May I ask who put the close-vote here? And why? And why without comment?

Comment: Sorry for the close vote, first I thought this would belong on superuser.com but then I saw that it cannot be done without programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, none of the given solutions satisfied me, so I coded it myself. :)

See here:

- http://github.com/albertz/helpers/blob/master/indent-spacestotabs.py
- http://github.com/albertz/helpers/blob/master/indent-tabtospaces.py

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the source language, you could try out [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).  It can do a large number of things relating to the indentation of source code, though it might be more complex than you need.

For example, if I give the following program to `indent -di0 <inputfile>`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
    int j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("x");
    }
  }
}
```

It will replace it with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("x");
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you need something stupid simple, there is the `expand/unexpand` commands.

Comment: `indent` doesn't work (it's Python -- tough I'm also searching for a solution which works in other cases too). `expand`/`unexpand` is too simple (basically like most other solutions given here). :)

Comment: Perhaps the reindent.py script at http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py will give a basis for what you need then?

Comment: Hey, that reindent.py looks mostly like what I wanted. :) Well, didn't looked much into it, not sure if it is only Python-only (which would have helped me right now but would not have been the general solution I was searching for). Coded it myself now...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to replace N spaces by a tab charater. For example in Python:

```
import re
re.sub('[ ]{4}', '\t', text)
```

Comment: It's not that easy. This for example would not only replace spaces used for indentation but also everywhere else (and it should not do that).

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. `sed -i` is your friend - `sed -i XXX.txt 's/^[ ]\{2\}/\t/g'`
2. You can't make regular expression to multiply the tab replacement by the space length.

Given my AWK-fu is not strong (and I don't know if it can do what #2 can't), I will write a PHP script to calculate the spaces and replace them with tabs.

Comment: Ok, that will at least only replace spaces in the beginning. Though it will not replace it multiple times. I probably will write a Python script which does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/ {2}/\t/g' file
```

Comment: It's not that easy. This for example would not only replace spaces used for indentation but also everywhere else (and it should not do that).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution in Python:

```
import re
import fileinput

pat = re.compile("^(  )+")

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    print pat.sub(lambda m: "\t" * (m.end() // 2), line, 1),
```

Comment: Ok, better solution than the others but it will not work if there are mixed spaces/tabs already. Sth. like `"\t  \t"` should become `"\t" * 3`.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the regex with `"^(  |\t)+"`? I think I don't exactly understand the requirements. __EDIT:__ that is *two* spaces in the new regex, the inline code markup unfortunately collapses spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert leading spaces (even interspersed with tabs) into tabs. Specify the number of spaces to convert by setting the variable. Stray spaces will be collapsed to nothing. Spaces and tabs that appear after any character other than space or tab will not be touched.

```
tstop=2
sed "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1\n\2/;h;s/[^[\n]*//;x;s/\n.*//;s/ \{$tstop\}/X/g;s/ //g;G;s/\n//g" inputfile
```

Example:

```
[space][space][tab][tab][space][space][space][tab][space]TEXT[space][space][space]
```

will be converted to

```
[tab][tab][tab][tab][tab]TEXT[space][space][space]
```

If that's not exactly what you're looking for, adjustments can be made.

Comment: Totally unreadable but looks like what I was searching for. :) Btw., shouldn't it be `...[tab][space]TEXT` in the output? At least that is what I want.

Comment: I'm removing all stray spaces. What would you want (for `tstop=2`) `[tab][space][tab]...TEXT` to look like? What about `[tab][space][space]TEXT`?

Comment: `[t][s][t]text` should become `[t][t]text`. `[t][s][s]text` should become `[t][t]text`. `[t][s]text` should stay the same.